# Subscribe on Code property changing with WhenAnyValue of items in list with ReactiveUI

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, reactiveui

I have the following class:

```
public sealed class TestViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private string _code;
    public string Code
    {
        get
        {

            return _code;
        }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _code, value); }
    }
}
```

And I have an `ObservableCollection<TestViewModel>`. This collection is changing, so I can't get a snapshot and use a combine subscribing.
I want to subscribe on Code property changing event for all items, then use Throttle on all of them and then execute a command. I think `WhenAnyValue` is what I want. But i don't know how to use `WhenAnyValue` for a property of an item in a mutable collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using ReactiveList with change tracking instead of the ObservableCollection. It exposes several observable that may be what you are looking for.

http://reactiveui.readthedocs.org/en/stable/basics/reactive-list/